# Any better way of adding number to ListView's ItemContainerStyle?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

I'm trying to extend my ListView's *ItemContainerStyle* a little and add a *TextBlock* with binding to a property. It should show *ListView.SelectedItems.Count*.

For now I've one working solution, but I'm not happy with it (I suspect that there is much easier way and probably more clean). It goes like this:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
  <!--Some code-->     
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
       <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <!--Some code-->
         <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding ElementName=contentPresenter, Path=DataContext}" Text="{Binding Number}" Foreground="Red"/>
```

The idea is very simple - I set the *DataContext* the same as `contentPresenter`'s, which means that if I've in my *ItemClass* a property *Number* and I put there `Item.Number = myList.SelectedItems.Count;` everything works fine.

But is there other way to do it in this Style? Without additional property in my *ItemClass*? Somehow maybe extend *ListView* or *ListViewItem*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought I could use `ElementName` binding to retrieve the `ListView`, and then bind the `Text` of your `TextBlock` to the `ListView`'s `SelectedItems.Count`. Something like the following -

```
<!-- this won't work -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=myList, Converter="{StaticResource GetCountConverter}"}" />
```

However, unlike the `SelectedItem` dependency property, this wouldn't work because `SelectedItems` is merely a normal read-only property.

A common workaround would be to create a static helper class with a couple of attached properties. Something like this -

```
public static class ListViewEx
{
    public static int GetSelectedItemsCount(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(SelectedItemsCountProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSelectedItemsCount(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectedItemsCountProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectedItemsCount", typeof(int), typeof(ListViewEx), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public static bool GetAttachListView(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AttachListViewProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachListView(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AttachListViewProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachListViewProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachListView", typeof(bool), typeof(ListViewEx), new PropertyMetadata(false, Callback));

    private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            var listView = d as ListView;
            if (listView == null) return;

            listView.SelectionChanged += (s, args) =>
            {
                SetSelectedItemsCount(listView, listView.SelectedItems.Count);
            };
        }
    }
```

Basically here I've created a `SelectedItemsCount` attached property to leverage data binding. Whenever the `SelectionChanged` is fired, the code updates the attached property to the `Count` of the `SelectedItems` so they are always in sync.

Then in the xaml, you will need to first attach the helper to the `ListView` (in order to retrieve the `ListView` instance and subscribe to its `SelectionChanged` event),

```
<ListView x:Name="myList" local:ListViewEx.AttachListView="true"
```

and lastly, update the binding in the `TextBlock` xaml.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:ListViewEx.SelectedItemsCount), ElementName=myList}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying your sample, but I'm not sure if it will be possible to use it in *Page.Resources* - due to `ElementName = myList`.

Comment: You are right, I've put your code to my example, where I'd enabled ItemClick, and I've srewed something up. Now works. DO you have an idea how to get rid off this ElementName - define one style which could be used among many pages?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. You mean you don't want to use ElementName binding?

Comment: Hmm I don't think so. RT doesn't support ancestor binding unfortunately.

Comment: I've searched a lot yesterday and I've the same conclusion as yours. I will leave the question unaccepted for few days (maybe there will be other ideas). Thank you for help.

Comment: @Romasz You could write an attached property that goes up the visual tree to the nearest `ListView` and "binds" to it. It wouldn't be very reusable, but might be what you need? You could make something generic, but that wouldn't be very easy and would be an overkill.

Comment: @yasen You are right, this way it also can be done. If you write this as an answer, you have my vote, though I would probaby accept Justin XL's. Nevertheless I think I'll stick to my idea, it's quite simple and universal.